# Remove # character from url with jQuery

Tags: jquery

With this jQuery I can change the url of my site from mysite.com/#oldurl to mysite.com/newurl:

```
$('.trigger').click(function() {
    history.pushState('data', '', 'newurl');
});
```

How can I make it so the # is always striped out and the rest of the url left. So mysite.com/#page2 becomes mysite.com/page2, mysite.com/#page3 becomes mysite.com/page3, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.trigger').click(function() {
 var final_url="";
if(your_url.indexOf('#') != -1)
{
  final_url=your_url.replace('#', '');
}

history.pushState('data', '', final_url);
});
```

Comment: In my console im getting: Uncaught ReferenceError: your_url is not defined main.js:5
(anonymous function) main.js:5
x.event.dispatch jquery.js:5095
v.handle

Comment: your_url is a variable which is to be assigned an url.did you assign your_url a link..check..its not assigned!!!

Answer (score 3):

U can use [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```
var newurl=oldurl.replace("#","");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
newurl = oldurl.replace(/#/g,"/");
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be misreading the question, My thought when you say `#` is the current URL minus the hash.

You can create a jQuery `a` element with `window.location` to build the current url. Use this variable to parse the current url parts. Also you might want to check if pushState is available before you use it.

```
if(history.pushState){
    var a = $('<a>', {href: window.location})[0];
    history.pushState(null, null, a.pathname+a.hash.substr(1));
}
```

Comment: I dont want to change the link. I need to change the page url to remove the # from whatever is there. So So mysite.com/#page2 will be changed to mysite.com/page2

Answer (score 0):

This is my use of "On a serious note"'s code:

```
$('.trigger').click(function() {

    var oldURL = window.location.hash;
//  console.log('newURL ', oldURL);

    var final_url="";
    final_url=oldURL.replace('#', '');
    history.pushState('data', '', final_url);

//  console.log('final_url', final_url);

});
```